# Python program that computes for the area of a polygon using coordinate method always ends up equal to zero

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was creating a program that computes for the area using the coordinate method with user inputted 2d coordinates. I'm asking for help because every time I run the program it always ends up equal to zero.

```
n= int(input("Enter number of corners:"))
TotalArea=0.0
for x in range (n):
    y=x
    a= input("Enter X%d coordinate:"%(x+1))
    b= input("Enter Y%d coordinate:"%(y+1))
    if (x,y)==1:
        x1=a
        y1=b
        TotalArea+= (x1*prevy-x2*prevx)
    elif 1<(x,y)<n:
        prevx=a
        prevy=b
        TotalArea+= (prevx*b-prevy*a)
    elif (x,y)==1:
        x1=a
        y1=b
        TotalArea+= (prevx*y1-prevy*x1)
    Area= abs(TotalArea)/2
    print Area
```

Comment: Expressions `(x,y)==1` and `1<(x,y)<n` don't probably return what you expect.

Comment: what values did `prevy` and `prevx` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i found a solution, sorry if i wasn't replying i was really absorbed in the class. @eumiro was right, the expressions didn't return what i expected. i fixed the variables to make them less confusing and i just fixed the levels in the indentation.

```
n= int(input("Enter number of corners:"))   
Area= 0.0
print "Enter Polygon corners"
for i in range (n):
    x= input("Enter X%d coordinate:"%(i+1))
    x= float(x)
    y= input("Enter Y%d coordinate:"%(i+1))
    y= float(y)
    if i== 0:
        x1= x
        y1= y
    else:
        Area+= (px*y- py*x)
    px= x
    py= y
Area+= (x*y1- y*x1)# i vow to never forget this part again
print "The Area is equal to %f"% (abs(Area)/ 2)
```